# QEMU: WARN (Unknown if this platform has Secure Guest support)

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

when I run `virt-host-validate` commend I get this warning

```
QEMU: Checking for secure guest support : WARN (Unknown if this platform has Secure Guest support)
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is possible that this tool does not check SG support for the Intel processors and you can ignore this warning. I have it as well. https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/master/tools/virt-host-validate-qemu.c

Comment: It looks like they check it only for AMD and IBM processors. Source: https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/a2196bc2389c6d87d523f71380615337cce2e7a3/src/qemu/qemu_capabilities.c#L4701